# List vhosts and IPs associated

Tags: apache, debian, vhosts

Is it possible to get a list of all vhosts, IPs in a server?
So I don't have to check every file at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ to know what is it on every server.
I need to get something like this:

```
+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| Server Alias |   IP Address    |    Document Root    |
+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| mysite.test  | 192.168.0.12:80 |  /home/User/mysite  |
+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following command

```
# apache2ctl -S
```

And with some awk magic have it in the desired format

To be exact try the following

```
# apachectl -S 2>&1 | perl -ne 'm@.*port\s+([0-9]+)\s+\w+\s+(\S+)\s+\((.+):.*@ && do { print "$2:$1\n\t$3\n"; $root = qx{grep DocumentRoot $3}; $root =~ s/^\s+//; print "\t$root\n" };'
```

Comment: Thank you! The "apache2ctl -S" worked just fine, but the last command didn't work, just shows the first line of the default file.

Comment: It worked for me on ubuntu 12.04.
Could you please post the output ?

Comment: Sure, here it is:

    caxamarca.miglos.com:80
        /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
        DocumentRoot /var/www

Comment: If you tried the following ? `# for i in `apachectl -S |grep namevhost |awk -F "(" {' print $2 '} | awk -F ":" {' print $1 '} `; do cat $i |grep DocumentRoot; cat $i |grep ServerName ; done`